# WCF REST JSON collection null with Twitter

Tags: json, wcf, rest, serialization, twitter

I'm issuing the friends/ids call like so:

```
GET /1.1/friends/ids.json?screen_name=blablabla HTTP/1.1
```

A valid response is issued:

```
{"ids":[97500486,32947624,8884440,2022687,28741369,33978239,10312111,950922,7682036,21688137,7696145,15876098],"next_cursor":0,"next_cursor_str":"0","previous_cursor":0,"previous_cursor_str":"0"}
```

My interface looks like this:

```
[OperationContract(Name = "ids.json")]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate="ids.json?user_id={userId}&screen_name={screenName}")]
FriendsIdsResponse Ids(long? userId, string screenName);

[DataContract]
public class FriendsIdsResponse
{
  public FriendsIdsResponse()
  {
  }

  [DataMember(Name = "ids")]
  public long[] Ids { get; set; }
  [DataMember(Name = "previous_cursor")]
  public int PreviousCursor { get; set; }
  [DataMember(Name = "next_cursor")]
  public int NextCursor { get; set; }
}
```

No matter what type Ids is (long[], IList, List, etc.), it always comes back null. If I instantiate it to an empty List in ctor, it has Count==0.

**UPDATE** WCF configs, as requested:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
        <endpoint contract="TA.Twitter.Service.IFriends, TA.Twitter.Interfaces"
                            address="https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/"
                            binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebHttpBinding"
                            ></endpoint>
    </client>
    <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WebHttpBinding" allowCookies="true">
                <security mode="Transport">
                </security>
            </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code you are using to call the twitter api and deserialize the response. Your contract and interface are fine so it's got to be the client code.

Comment: @TommyGrovnes but I am not using any custom code, it's all WCF. Essentially, I create a ChannelFactory<T> and then .CreateChannel() which gives me T (IFriends in this case).

Comment: How about your wcf config then, bindings etc ?

Comment: @TommyGrovnes see question update.

Comment: What about authentication ?

Comment: @TommyGrovnes as you may or may not know, Twitter uses OAuth, which works as expected. I'm implementing IClientMessageInspector to add the "Authorization" HTTP header. The code is pretty complex, particularly signature calculation, 3-legged auth, etc. Do you think the HTTP header could be throwing this off? The response Content-Type is "text/json".

Comment: Just curious since I know it's quite complex, but usually authentication is an all or nothing deal, it fails totally or not at all.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but are you restricted to use WCF to invoke Tweeter API ?
I'm a big fan of WCF, but for Twitter there are already many .net Librairies. I understand there is a challenge in WCF but I prefer to not reinvent the wheel each time.

[Tweetsharp](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp) seems to be a popular .net library for Twitter API access.

Suppose you already have OAuth tokens, get friends is done with less than 10 lines of code.

```
    var service = new TweetSharp.TwitterService("consumerKey", "consumerSecret");
    service.AuthenticateWith("accessToken", "accessTokenSecret");

    var friends = service.ListFriendIdsOf(new TweetSharp.ListFriendIdsOfOptions() { ScreenName = "blabla" });
    foreach (var friend in friends)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("new friend :{0} ", friend);
    }
```

Less than 10 lines, less than 10 minutes, seems to be a good compromise

Comment: I am aware of .NET Twitter libraries but was hoping to get WCF to work. Seems to be straightforward JSON response, should be an easy task.

Comment: yes for sure, but you need to create operation & datacontract for each Tweeter API you want to use and someone already did this for you.